# PostgreSQL - can I use logical replication from a replica's WAL?

Tags: postgresql, replication, amazon-rds, postgresql-9.5, aws

I would like to use logical replication. However, as PostgreSQL works now, it can eat up the whole disk and then block the database. Especially in Amazon Web Services RDS, this is a problem because RDS won't give you `SUPERUSER` role so you could connect and turn off the slots.

So I set up an RDS replica and set `rds.logical_replication` to `1`. But it seems that RDS replica doesn't react to that - `SHOW ALL` says `wal_level = hot_standby` while it should be `logical`.

This is what I want to achieve:

```
RDS master
    WAL --> RDS replica
                logical replication ON
                WAL + wal2json  ---->    pg_recvlogical on remote client
```

**Is this possible?**

Reference: [`wal_level`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/runtime-config-wal.html#GUC-WAL-LEVEL)

When I try to create a slot, I get:

> FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for replication connection from host "...", user "postgres", SSL off

This looks like AWS is not putting the right entries to `pg_hba.conf` - i.e. does not allow the postgres user to create the replication slots.

Is my assumption right? Is there any way around that?

Answer (score 4):

You need to assign **rds_superuser** and **rds_replication** role to the user.

Refer here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-rds-for-postgresql-new-minor-versions-logical-replication-dms-and-more/

Comment: Thanks, but I replicate from RDS to RDS. The problem seems to be that `rds.logical_replication` doesn't do the necessary changes in the replica.

Comment: My question is rather whether I am pursuing an imposible setup, not supported by PostgreSQL.

Comment: Yup, you are correct, if you need to setup RDS to RDS, the option is in preview mode, RDS postgres10(or 11), this feature is available. But you can't use this for general RDS.

Comment: Do I get you right: RDS PostgreSQL 10+ will have an experimentally allow RDS replica WAL at logical level and the replica will be able to have logical replication slots? And no way for 9.x?